# Troubles AJAX Integration with Django

Tags: django, ajax

When I save products from ajax to db, it always redirects me to failed page and saying 500 server error

views.py

```
from cart.cart import Cart
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Order, OrderItem, ShippingAddress

# Create your views here.

def checkout(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        try:
            shipping_address = ShippingAddress.objects.get(user=request.user.id)
            context = {'shipping': shipping_address}
            return render(request, 'payment/checkout.html', context=context)
        except:
            return render(request, 'payment/checkout.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'payment/checkout.html')


def complete_order(request):
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        address1 = request.POST.get('address1')
        address2 = request.POST.get('address2')
        city = request.POST.get('city')
        state = request.POST.get('state')
        zipcode = request.POST.get('zipcode')
        print(name)
        shipping_address = (address1 + "\n" + address2 + "\n" +
        city + "\n" + state + "\n" + zipcode
        )

        cart = Cart(request)

        total_cost = cart.get_total()

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            order = Order.objects.create(full_name=name, email=email, shipping_address=shipping_address,
            amount_paid=total_cost, user=request.user)
            order_id = order.pk

            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(order_id=order_id, product=item['product'], quantity=item['qty'],
                price=item['price'], user=request.user)


        else:
            order = Order.objects.create(full_name=name, email=email, shipping_address=shipping_address,
            amount_paid=total_cost)
            order_id = order.pk
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(order_id=order_id, product=item['product'], quantity=item['qty'],
                price=item['price'])
        order_success = True
        response = JsonResponse({'success':order_success})
        return response
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('checkout', views.checkout, name='checkout'),
    path('complete-order', views.complete_order, name='complete-order'),
    path('payment-success', views.payment_success, name='payment-success'),
    path('payment-failed', views.payment_failed, name='payment-failed'),

]
```

checkout.html

```
{% include "store/base.html" %}


{% load static %}


{% block content %}

<style>
    
    body 
    {
        
        background-color: gray;
    
    }


</style>


    <body>

        <br>

        <div class="container bg-white shadow-md p-5" style="width:500px; border-radius:20px;">

            <form id="form" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();">

                <div>

                    <h3> <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp; Complete your order </h3>

                    <p> Please enter in the relevant information below. </p>
 


                    <hr>

                    <br>

                    <div class="form-field">
                    
                        <input class="form-control validate" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Full name*" autocomplete="off" value="{{shipping.full_name}}" required>

                    </div>


                    <br>


                    <div class="form-field">

                        <input class="form-control validate" id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email address*" autocomplete="off" value="{{shipping.email}}" required>

                    </div>

                    
                    <br>

                    
                    <div class="form-field">

                        <input class="form-control validate" id="address1" type="text" placeholder="Address 1*" autocomplete="off" value="{{shipping.address1}}" required>

                    </div>


                    <br>


                    <div class="form-field">

                        <input class="form-control validate" id="address2" type="text" placeholder="Address 2*" autocomplete="off" value="{{shipping.address2}}" required>

                    </div>


                    <br>


                    <div class="form-field">

                        <input class="form-control validate" id="city" type="text" placeholder="City*" autocomplete="off" value="{{shipping.city}}" required>

                    </div>


                    <br>


                    <div class="form-field">

                        <input class="form-control" id="state" type="text" placeholder="State (Optional)" autocomplete="off" value="{{shipping.state}}">

                    </div>


                    <br>


                    <div class="form-field">

                        <input class="form-control" id="zipcode" type="text" placeholder="Zip code (Optional)" autocomplete="off" value="{{shipping.zipcode}}">

                    </div>
            
                </div>

                <br>



            <button id="complete-order" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn text-white"> &nbsp; Complete order </button>
            

                <br>

            </form>


        </div>

        

        <br>


    </body>

    <script>

        $(document).on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{% url "complete-order" %}',
                data: {
                    name: $('#name').val(),
                    email: $('#email').val(),
                    address1: $('#address1').val(),
                    address2: $('#address2').val(),
                    city: $('#city').val(),
                    state: $('#state').val(),
                    zipcode: $('#zipcode').val(),
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{csrf_token}}",
                    action: 'post'
                },
                success: function(json) {
                    window.location.replace("{% url 'payment-success' %}");
                },
                error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
                    window.location.replace("{% url 'payment-failed' %}");
                }
            });
        });
        </script>
        
{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.db import models
    from store.models import Product
    
    class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
        full_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
        address1 = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        address2 = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
        state = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
        zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    
        class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = "Shipping Address"
    
        def __str__(self):
            return 'Shipping Address - ' + str(self.id)
    
    class Order(models.Model):
        full_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
        shippingAddress = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
        amount_paid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
        date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return 'Order - #' + str(self.id)
        
    class OrderItem(models.Model):
        order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
        quantity = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(default=1)
        price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return 'Order Item - #' + str(self.id)
```

cart/cart.py

```
        from decimal import Decimal
        
        from store.models import Product
        
        
        class Cart():
        
            def __init__(self, request):
                self.session = request.session
                cart = self.session.get('session_key')
                if 'session_key' not in request.session:
                    cart = self.session['session_key'] = {}
                self.cart = cart
        
        
            def add(self, product, product_qty):
                product_id = str(product.id)
                if product_id in self.cart:
                    self.cart[product_id]['qty'] = product_qty
                else:
                    self.cart[product_id] = {'price': str(product.price), 'qty': product_qty}
                self.session.modified = True
        
        
            def delete(self, product):
                product_id = str(product)
                if product_id in self.cart:
                    del self.cart[product_id]
                self.session.modified = True
        
        
        
            def update(self, product, qty):
                product_id = str(product)
                product_quantity = qty
                if product_id in self.cart:
                    self.cart[product_id]['qty'] = product_quantity
                self.session.modified = True
        
            def __len__(self):
        
                return sum(item['qty'] for item in self.cart.values())
        
        
        
            def __iter__(self):
                all_product_ids = self.cart.keys()
                products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=all_product_ids)
                cart = self.cart.copy()
                for product in products:
                    cart[str(product.id)]['product'] = product
                for item in cart.values():
                    item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
                    item['total'] = item['price'] * item['qty']
                    yield item
        
            
            def get_total(self):
                return sum(Decimal(item['price']) * item['qty'] for item in self.cart.values())
```

store/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("list-category", args=[self.slug])
    

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='product', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='un-branded')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
    price = models.FloatField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'products'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

if user is authenticated and he click on "Complete order" it should save all products to db with user's name and redirect to success page. But everytime it redirects to failed page and saying Error 500 complete-oreder

Comment: What is the output of the console from the 500 error...these are very specific in logs and show your line where the error occurs

Answer (score 0):

In your `complete_order` view, you're creating `Order` and `OrderItem` objects. How you're using `order_id=order_id` when creating `OrderItem` instances is not correct. As OrderItem's order field is a `ForeignKey` to `Order`, you should pass the `Order` instance directly, not just its `ID`. You should correct it like this:

```
for item in cart:
    OrderItem.objects.create(order=order, product=item['product'], quantity=item['qty'], price=item['price'], user=request.user)
```

Comment: anyway is has the same error
[08/Feb/2024 15:38:36] "POST /payment/complete-order HTTP/1.1" 500 70871

Comment: @sakwenn provide your `Cart` function as well as `Product` model class from `store.models` so I can try the code in my local and see the error better.

Comment: ty, updated and provided above